# Numpy Array Broadcasting with different dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I a little confused by the broadcasting rules of numpy. Suppose you want to perform an axis-wise scalar product of a higher dimension array to reduce the array dimension by one (basically to perform a weighted summation along one axis):

```
from numpy import *

A = ones((3,3,2))
v = array([1,2])

B = zeros((3,3))

# V01: this works
B[0,0] = v.dot(A[0,0])

# V02: this works
B[:,:] = v[0]*A[:,:,0] + v[1]*A[:,:,1] 

# V03: this doesn't
B[:,:] = v.dot(A[:,:])
```

Why does V03 not work?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.dot(a, b)` operates [over the last axis of a and the second-to-last of b](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html). So for your particular case in your question,you could always go with :

```
>>> a.dot(v)
array([[ 3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.]])
```

If you want to keep the `v.dot(a)` order, you need to get the axis into position, which can easily be achieved with [`np.rollaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html):

```
>>> v.dot(np.rollaxis(a, 2, 1))
array([[ 3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.]])
```

I don't like `np.dot` too much, unless it is for the obvious matrix or vector multiplication, because it is very strict about the output dtype when using the optional `out` parameter. Joe Kington has mentioned it already, but if you are going to be doing this type of things, get used to `np.einsum`: once you get the hang of the syntax, it will cut down the amount of time you spend worrying about reshaping things to a minimum:

```
>>> a = np.ones((3, 3, 2))
>>> np.einsum('i, jki', v, a)
array([[ 3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.]])
```

Not that it is too relevant in this case, but it is also ridiculously fast:

```
In [4]: %timeit a.dot(v)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.43 us per loop

In [5]: %timeit v.dot(np.rollaxis(a, 2, 1))
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.49 us per loop

In [7]: %timeit np.tensordot(v, a, axes=(0, 2))
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.9 us per loop

In [8]: %timeit np.einsum('i, jki', v, a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.91 us per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`tensordot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html), in this particular case.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.ones((3,3,2))
v = np.array([1,2])

print np.tensordot(v, A, axes=(0, 2))
```

This yields:

```
array([[ 3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.]])
```

The `axes=(0,2)` indicates that `tensordot` should sum over the first axis in `v` and the third axis in `A`.  (Also have a look at [`einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), which is more flexible, but harder to understand if you're not used to the notation.)

If speed is a consideration, `tensordot` is considerably faster than using `apply_along_axes` for small arrays.

```
In [14]: A = np.ones((3,3,2))

In [15]: v = np.array([1,2])

In [16]: %timeit np.tensordot(v, A, axes=(0, 2))
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.6 us per loop

In [17]: %timeit np.apply_along_axis(v.dot, 2, A)
1000 loops, best of 3: 258 us per loop
```

(The difference is less apparent for large arrays due to a constant overhead, though `tensordot` is consistently faster.)

Comment: I find numpy tensordot axes totally confusing.  Can you elaborate?  I want to multiple a (10,3,2) tensor by a (3,5) tensor to get a (2) tensor.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`numpy.apply_along_axis()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) for this:

```
In [35]: np.apply_along_axis(v.dot, 2, A)
Out[35]: 
array([[ 3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.]])
```

The reason I think `V03` doesn't work is that it's no different to:

```
B[:,:] = v.dot(A)
```

i.e. it tries to compute the dot product along the outermost axis of `A`.