# Numpy, python: automatically expand dimensions of arrays when broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Consider the following exercise in Numpy array broadcasting.

```
import numpy as np
v = np.array([[1.0, 2.0]]).T # column array

A2 = np.random.randn(2,10) # 2D array
A3 = np.random.randn(2,10,10) # 3D

v * A2 # works great

# causes error: 
v * A3 # error
```

I know the Numpy rules for broadcasting, and I'm familiar with `bsxfun` functionality in Matlab. I understand why attempting to broadcast a (2,1) array into a (2,N,N) array fails, and that I have to reshape the (2,1) array into a (2,1,1) array before this broadcasting goes through.

My question is: is there any way to tell Python to automatically pad the dimensionality of an array when it attempts to broadcast, without me having to specifically tell it the necessary dimension?

I *don't want to explicitly couple* the (2,1) vector with the multidimensional array it's going to be broadcast against---otherwise I could do something stupid and absurdly ugly like `mult_v_A = lambda v,A: v.reshape([v.size] + [1]*(A.ndim-1)) * A`. I don't know ahead of time if the "A" array will be 2D or 3D or N-D.

Matlab's `bsxfun` broadcasting functionality implicitly pads the dimensions as needed, so I'm hoping there's something I could do in Python.

Comment: My view is that this is a feature and not a bug. For example, suppose you had a 2-by-1 column vector `v` and then you had a 2-by-2-by-10 `ndarray`. Do you want to reshape `v` to have shape `(2,1,1)` or shape `(1,2,1)`? If you just pad the dimensions, it could be ambiguous to the user. Forcing an explicit reshape is a better general procedure, and leave it to the user to write a special function to perform the reshaping automatically if the user has a fixed convention. But it's not good to make a global `numpy` dimension-padder that forces a convention upon you. It would be too easy to misuse.

Comment: -1 @EMS. This ambiguity is readily solved by specifying that the first non-singleton dimension will be used in the broadcast. This attitude of "This way it's better" is totally inappropriate for systems used by professional programmers and applied mathematicians---this is a flaw in terms of illegibility and complectedness, not a feature.

Comment: Also, though the questions start out differently, this is a possible duplicate of: < http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296944/numpy-array-broadcasting-with-different-dimensions >. I think `numpy.apply_along_axis` and `numpy.tensordot` in particular seem more than sufficient for this kind of thing, while still leaving the nice property that the programmer must make some explicit reference to the way that ambiguous dimension changes should occur for broadcasting.

Comment: I'd expect `apply_along_axis` to totally destroy performance by de-vectorizing the array operation. Also, broadcasting is much more useful than just multiplication via `tensordot`.

Comment: @EMS, I expected you to be a professional user---it's hard to see foibles in one's daily tools as foibles; instead we like to praise them. As unutbu's answer illustrates, Numpy has already chosen to resolve such ambiguities, using simply the *reverse* of my suggestion: Numpy is perfectly happy broadcasting (10, 2, 2) and (2, 1) arrays, and broadcasts over the *last* non-singleton dimension because it works *backwards* along the dimension tuple.

Comment: It's unfortunate that NumPy provides ambiguous dimension padding *at all*. But I'm happy you've found something that can resolve your issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's ugly, but this will work:

```
(v.T * A3.T).T
```

If you don't give it any arguments, transposing reverses the shape tuple, so you can now rely on the broadcasting rules to do their magic. The last transpose returns everything to the right order.

Comment: It is actually less ugly than what I had after studying @unutbu's answer, which was `np.swapaxes(v.T * np.swapaxes(A3,0,-1), 0, -1)`! Knowing that transpose reverses all dimensions makes this much neater. At least users will see these transposes and hopefully think "Ok there's broadcasting going on here, with just a tiny touch of funkiness to make the dimensions line up, ok, I'm ok". Thanks chief.

Answer (score 9):

NumPy broadcasting adds additional axes on the left.

So if you arrange your arrays so the shared axes are on the right and the broadcastable axes are on the left, then you can use broadcasting with no problem:

```
import numpy as np
v = np.array([[1.0, 2.0]])  # shape (1, 2)

A2 = np.random.randn(10,2) # shape (10, 2)
A3 = np.random.randn(10,10,2) # shape (10, 10, 2)

v * A2  # shape (10, 2)

v * A3 # shape (10, 10, 2)
```

Comment: This at least is a half-way solution. The established convention in my application is unfortunately that vectors like `v` are column arrays. Assuming I didn't want to reorganize the code (and my users) to expect row arrays, I am debating whether a function that swaps dimensions to do a broadcast multiply is really any less complected than a reshape operation that intertwines `A` and `v` in my original post.

Comment: Is there some reason why Numpy adds dimensions to the left, but not on the right? It seems arbitrary but perhaps there's some important rationale related to memory or algebra?

Comment: Possibly answering my own (sub-)question, is it because broadcasting starts at arrays' trailing dimensions and works leftward, and keeps adding dimensions as needed, as long as the rules are met? Interesting!

Comment: NumPy arrays are in C-contiguous order (last-index varies the fastest) by default. So adding additional axes on the left is essentially costless -- only the `strides` and `shape` attributes have to change, while the underlying data can remain the same. If NumPy arrays were in F-contiguous order by default, then broadcasting would work most naturally by adding axes on the right.