# How to subtract along axis=0 in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a matrix `mat` like below;

```
mat = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
```

and a list `s = [1, 2, 5].`
I have to subtract along axis=1. I did as follow and it works..

```
mat - s = array([[ 0,  0, -2],
                [ 3,  3,  1],
                [ 6,  6,  4]])
```

However, if I subtract along axis=0;
ie,

```
mat - s[:,None]
```

I get errors.

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577336/numpy-python-automatically-expand-dimensions-of-arrays-when-broadcasting

Comment: Start with`s=np.array([1,2,3])`, an array, not a list.

Comment: In numpys c origin it i an array, but in python the term list is better and correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little hack:

```
s = np.array([1,2,5])  
(mat.T - s).T
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```

Edit: `.T` does not change anything if `s` is `1d` so you can remove it.

Comment: `s.T` doesn't do anything if `s` is 1d

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with the use of `[:,None]`, but your definition of `s` was wrong.

```
In [128]: mat = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])                                                     
In [129]: s = [1, 2, 5]                                                                                         
In [130]: mat  - s                                                                                              
Out[130]: 
array([[ 0,  0, -2],
       [ 3,  3,  1],
       [ 6,  6,  4]])
```

In this subtraction, `s` has automatically been 'promoted' to numpy array.

The `[..,...]` indexing does not work with a **list**:

```
In [131]: s[:,None]                                                                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-131-bafcfb7b67c1> in <module>
----> 1 s[:,None]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

The tuple in this error is the comma expression: `s[:, None]` is the same as `s[(:,None)]`.  The python parser passes a tuple to the `s.__getitem__` method.  `numpy` arrays handle tuples (multidimensonal indexing), lists don't.

If we start with an array, then we can apply the reshape, and perform the desired subtraction:

```
In [132]: sa = np.array(s)                                                                                      
In [133]: sa                                                                                                    
Out[133]: array([1, 2, 5])
In [134]: sa[:,None]                                                                                            
Out[134]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [5]])
In [135]: mat - sa[:,None]                                                                                      
Out[135]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```

`sa` is 1d, so transpose doesn't change anything:

```
In [136]: sa.T                                                                                                  
Out[136]: array([1, 2, 5])
```